# How to implement this keyboard?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, actionbarsherlock, calculator

This is the keyboard from the Sony Xperia calculator app (ICS):

[image]

[image]

It can be slid left to bring up the scientific buttons.

[image]

- How do I implement a keyboard like this?
- Can the State Pager from Action Bar Sherlock be used? (how?)

My app's **minSdkVersion is 8**, targetSdkVersion is 17.

If not any other alternatives to implement both the basic and scientific keyboard (**mine has lots of keys**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement this by using [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).

> ViewFlipper is a simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

So you can design multiple screen and show it using `viewflipper`

Comment: Huh. That never occurred to me. Thanks

Comment: sorry , didn't get you.. is it helpful for you?